# Join condition retrieving undesired answer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables and is as follows

```
select Event_ID,[Gross Salary] from tblEar where Event_ID=14
```

Result:

```
Event_ID  Gross Salary
14        56128
14        51984
14        42028
```

And:

```
select EventId, [Order Date],Amount from tblBudget where EventId=14
```

Result:

```
EventId Order Date Amount
14      10/10/2011 20000
14      10/10/2011 20000
14      20/03/2012 2500
14      02/04/2012 -50000
```

if i write a join statment on these 2 tables to get it is retrieving duplicate records.I used Distinct But no Positive Result.

```
select DISTINCT tba.[Order Date],ISNULL(tba.Amount,0),ISNULL(te.[Gross Salary],0) from tblBudget tba 
                     join
                         tblEar  te on tba.EventId=te.Event_ID  where tba.EventId=14
```

I got the following ans:

```
Order Date (No column name) (No column name)
2011-10-10 20000.00         42028.00
2011-10-10 20000.00         51984.00
2011-10-10 20000.00         56128.00
2012-03-20 2500.00          42028.00
2012-03-20 2500.00          51984.00
2012-03-20 2500.00          56128.00
2012-04-02 -50000.00        42028.00
2012-04-02 -50000.00        51984.00
2012-04-02 -50000.00        56128.00
```

Can any one show the Way to get Accuarate data

Comment: I've formatted your question so that the queries and results can be read (I also switched the order of the first two queries with respect to the results, since the result sets seem to match the queries better). But you haven't told us what result you're *expecting*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to group the data and aggregate the amounts:

```
SELECT tba.[Order Date], SUM(tba.Amount), SUM(te.[Gross Salary])
FROM tblBudget tba 
JOIN tblEar te on tba.EventId = te.Event_ID
WHERE tba.EventId = 14
GROUP BY tba.[Order Date]
```